# Python - Finding the average of a value in parallel dictionaries

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, counter

So I have some .csv data files I have to clean up. An example of one of the lines of data is:

```
u[i] = {'age': '44', 'salary': '117681.0', 'suburb': None, 'language': 'English'}
```

I have filtered out the data I dont want and have returned multiple rows of relevant dictionaries. eg:

```
{'age': '44', 'salary': '117681.0', 'suburb': None}
{'age': '34', 'salary': '56456.0', 'suburb': 'Frankston'}
{'age': '37', 'salary': '59370.0', 'suburb': 'Richmond'}
{'age': '44', 'salary': '91399.0', 'suburb': 'Collingwood'}
{'age': '36', 'salary': '74437.0', 'suburb': 'Toorak'}
{'age': '41', 'salary': '89121.0', 'suburb': 'Frankston'}
```

I now want to sum up the salary from each of these dictionaries to find the average salary, but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

I've tried isolating just the salary values and using counters but I cant seem to get that to work. I've also tried making lists that I can loop through but I can't seem to get all the values on one single list. The problem for me is that when I isolate the values they are parallel values/lists and I don't know how to work with it.

Would really appreciate any help, this has been driving me crazy! Thanks!

Here's my code so far, but I haven't really got anything worth looking at at this stage:

```
def average_salary(data, lower_age, upper_age): 
    u = dict(sorted(data_cleaned.items()))
    count = 0  

    for i in u:
        age = u[i]['age']
        sal = u[i]['salary']
        tally = 0

        if age is not None and sal is not None and lower_age < float(age) < upper_age:
            tally += float(u[i]['salary'])
            print(u[i]['salary'])
```

Comment: While @blue_note solution works well for your specific question, it looks like you want to perform operations on tabular data from a `csv`. Hence, you may want to look into a more specialized library for doing these kind of stuff like `pandas` or `numpy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gather salaries in a list

```
salaries = [float(my_dict['salary']) for my_dict in my_dicts]
average = sum(salaries) / len(salaries)
```

Comment: sorry I'm a bit confused (new to coding), would the my_dict['salary'] for my code be equivalent to u[i]['salary'] ? and what exactly is my_dicts representing?

Comment: @user10276362: `my_dicts` is the name of the list containing all your dictionaries (probably the variable `u`, if I understand correctly). The rest is a *list comprehension* (look it up, it's very useful for making the code shorter)

Answer (score 2):

assume you made it into a list:

```
i = [{'age': '44', 'salary': '117681.0', 'suburb': None},
{'age': '34', 'salary': '56456.0', 'suburb': 'Frankston'},
{'age': '37', 'salary': '59370.0', 'suburb': 'Richmond'},
{'age': '44', 'salary': '91399.0', 'suburb': 'Collingwood'},
{'age': '36', 'salary': '74437.0', 'suburb': 'Toorak'},
{'age': '41', 'salary': '89121.0', 'suburb': 'Frankston'}]

age_avg = sum(int(item["age"]) for item in i) / len(i)
salary_avg = sum(float(item["salary"]) for item in i) / len(i)

print (age_avg, salary_avg)
```

Result:

```
39.333333333333336 81410.66666666667
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have pandas installed then you can do this or install using `pip install pandas` or use install using anaconda

```
import pandas as pd
a=[{'age': '44', 'salary': '117681.0', 'suburb': None},
{'age': '34', 'salary': '56456.0', 'suburb': 'Frankston'},
{'age': '37', 'salary': '59370.0', 'suburb': 'Richmond'},
{'age': '44', 'salary': '91399.0', 'suburb': 'Collingwood'},
{'age': '36', 'salary': '74437.0', 'suburb': 'Toorak'},
{'age': '41', 'salary': '89121.0', 'suburb': 'Frankston'}]
df=pd.DataFrame(a)
df['salary']=pd.to_numeric(df['salary'],errors='coerce')
df['age']=pd.to_numeric(df['age'],errors='coerce')
print(df['salary'].mean())
print(df['age'].mean())
```

**Output**

```
81410.66666666667
39.333333333333336
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose also a solution like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
import numpy as np

u=[];
u.append({'age': '44', 'salary': '117681.0', 'suburb': None})
u.append({'age': '34', 'salary': '56456.0', 'suburb': 'Frankston'})
u.append({'age': '37', 'salary': '59370.0', 'suburb': 'Richmond'})
u.append({'age': '44', 'salary': '91399.0', 'suburb': 'Collingwood'})
u.append({'age': '36', 'salary': '74437.0', 'suburb': 'Toorak'})
u.append({'age': '41', 'salary': '89121.0', 'suburb': 'Frankston'})
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
def avg_salary(data,lower_age,upper_age):
    salaries = [float(val['salary']) for val in u if float(val['age'])>lower_age and float(val['age'])<upper_age];
    return sum(salaries)/len(salaries)
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
print avg_salary(u,5,65)
```